# get all comma seperated values of a string using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a field having values like

```
ID, Value
----------
1  ,Camera,photography,song
```

. I want to split this to

```
ID, value
----------
1, Camera
1, photography
1, song
```

How can i accomplish this in mysql Database

Comment: ya I knw. Is there any method to explode these

Comment: Poor database design? Reconsider a normalized structure that would be much more effective than finding a quick workaround.

Comment: @revo To be fair, that appears to be the direction in which the OP is heading.